# Code that checks whether there is a holiday by calling another microservice

Tags: java, spring, jwt

I call another microservice to check whether there is any holiday on any particular day. This will then add a comment in the db if the rest call doesn't fetch an empty list(a list of size 1).

Here is the code in service:

```
    public void updateMeetingStatus() {
        List<DialogueEntity> dialogueEntities = dialogueDBRepo.getChildDialogueToUpdate();
        dialogueEntities.forEach(dialogueEntity -> {
            if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(checkAndMarkSkipped(dialogueEntity))) {
                logger.info("Holiday detected for updateMeetingStatus");
                dialogueEntity.setComment(
                        "Dialogue Skipped because originator/participant location has holiday on this particular date!");
            }
            updateDialogueStatus(dialogueEntity, DialogueStatus.SKIPPED.getStatus());
        });
        dialogueDBRepo.saveAll(dialogueEntities);

        List<DialogueEntity> parentDialogues = dialogueDBRepo.getParentDialoguesToUpdate();
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(parentDialogues)) {
            parentDialogues = parentDialogues.stream()
                    .map(dialogueEntity -> updateDialogueStatus(dialogueEntity, DialogueStatus.CLOSED.getStatus()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            dialogueDBRepo.saveAll(parentDialogues);
        }
    }
```

```
private Boolean checkAndMarkSkipped(DialogueEntity entity) {
        String originator = entity.getOriginatorNtnet();
        EmployeeHierarchyEntity originatorLoc = hierarchyDBRepo.findByNtNetId(originator);
        String originatorLocation = originatorLoc.getLocation();
        String participant = entity.getParticipantNtnet();
        EmployeeHierarchyEntity participantLoc = hierarchyDBRepo.findByNtNetId(participant);
        String participantLocation = participantLoc.getLocation();
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(!checkIfHolidayExists(entity.getDateOfDialogue(), originatorLocation))
                || Boolean.TRUE.equals(!checkIfHolidayExists(entity.getDateOfDialogue(), participantLocation))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

```
private Boolean checkIfHolidayExists(LocalDate dateOfDialogue, String originatorLoc) {
        List<Date> date = restClientService.getHolidaysBetweenDates(
                Date.from(dateOfDialogue.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()),
                Date.from(dateOfDialogue.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()), originatorLoc,
                JwtGenerator.generateJwt(""));
        return date.isEmpty();
    }
```

```
@Override
    public List<Date> getHolidaysBetweenDates(Date fromDate, Date toDate, String holidayLocation, String token) {
        ResponseEntity<List<Date>> response = holidayServiceRestClient.getHolidaysBetweenDates(holidayLocation, fromDate, toDate, token);
        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            return response.getBody();
        } else if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) {
            logger.error("Holidays not found!");
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

`JwtGenerator`

```
public class JwtGenerator {

    private JwtGenerator(){

    }
    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "${jwt.config.secrate_key}";

    public static String generateJwt(String subject) {
        long nowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Date now = new Date(nowMillis);

        long expirationMillis = nowMillis + 3600000; // Set expiration time to 1 hour from now
        Date expiration = new Date(expirationMillis);

        return Jwts.builder()
                    .setSubject(subject)
                    .setIssuedAt(now)
                    .setExpiration(expiration)
                    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, SECRET_KEY)
                    .compact();
        }


}
```

Comment: Please do not post fragments of your code. Post it in its entirety.

Answer (score 2):

Well... from what I've managed to understand, your code is designed to update the meeting status based on whether there is a holiday on the meeting date for either the originator or the participant. The code makes use of a separate microservice to fetch holidays and check if the meeting date is a holiday or not. If a holiday is detected, the meeting status is updated with a comment stating that it was skipped due to a holiday at the location.

Right?

The logic seems to be clear and functional, but there are a few suggestions to improve the code:

- Use Java 8 features - prefer Optional and functional programming constructs for better readability and conciseness.
- Simplify some of the conditions in the `checkAndMarkSkipped` method.
- Consider using `LocalDate` instead of Date for more modern date handling in the `getHolidaysBetweenDates` method
- Replace `Boolean` with the primitive boolean in `checkAndMarkSkipped` method, and simplified the conditionals
- Replace `Date` with LocalDate in getHolidaysBetweenDates method